# What makes theatrical blood visually discernible from real blood?

Tags: effects

Of course, every blood scene in films, TV and theater will be fake. Real blood would have *many* sanitary issues, some psychological concerns, and wouldn't be nearly as convenient as artificial alternatives.

But if you were to purposefully drop your suspension of disbelief, are there any explicit tests you can ask for the visual appearance and motion of blood in a blood scene that makes it distinct to the hypothetical situation of the scene being real, even among the most realistic, best-executed blood scenes?

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing that second paragraph. Maybe I need coffee. Maybe that's a contrived phrasing. I'm not sure yet.

Comment: you mean "how do I know if the blood I'm seeing in this movie is fake"? What's the second paragraph about?

Comment: You could have a good look at the famous *chestburster* scene from Alien & tell us if you can tell the difference. That was real blood... & real reactions  http://www.cinemablography.org/blog/behind-the-scenes-making-of-the-chestburster-scene-from-alien

Comment: @Tetsujin wasn't that pig's blood? anyway, look at Django Unchained and watch the scene where Di Caprio's character breaks a glass and cuts his hand, then proceeds to, well, "smear" his blood on another. that was all real.

Comment: If you're deliberately trying to find the "fakeness" in a given gore scene, I expect you'd have better luck examining the *wounds inflicted* rather than the blood that pours out of them.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question but I confess I don't **really** undertand the purpose behind it.Further clarification/explanation is probably required. At the moment it seems to be "how to i make the best fake blood".

Comment: http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2013/10/22/movie_blood_recipe_and_history_from_hershey_s_to_corn_syrup_and_beyond.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind theatrical blood is that it's supposed to have a nearly identical look, color and density of real blood.  It's engineered that way, if "engineered" is the correct term.  So, in effect, you *shouldn't* be able to tell real blood from theatrical blood, at least not from a moviegoer perspective.  On-set, it may spatter slightly differently and there's no coagulation agent like real blood, but most movie scenes involving any type of gore usually aren't focused so much on the minutia that you would notice.